# How to sort a $_POST array by date string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a POST array passed on submission of a form. I loop through it and put the results into a table using this:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr><td>Exam Date</td><td>Subject Name</td><td>Subject Code</td><td>AM/PM</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$rowCount =  count($_POST['exam_code_input']);
//var_dump($_POST); 
    for($i=0; $i<$rowCount; $i++)
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['exam_date_input'][$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['exam_code_input'][$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['exam_title'][$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['exam_time_input'][$i]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to sort the table rows by the date. At the moment it puts the entries into the table by index. This is the `var_dump($_POST)`

```
array(13) { 
    ["your_name"]=> string(8) "Ian TEST" 
    ["candidate_number"]=> string(5) "12345" 
    ["centre_number"]=> string(4) "TEST" 
    ["school_year"]=> string(2) "12" 
    ["email"]=> string(23) "ianbutler82@yahoo.co.uk" 
    ["mobile_number"]=> string(11) "12345455676" 
    ["exam_board"]=> string(2) "-1" 
    ["exam_date_input"]=> array(7) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "05/16/2017" 
            [1]=> string(10) "05/08/2017" 
            [2]=> string(10) "05/12/2017" 
            [3]=> string(10) "05/25/2017" 
            [4]=> string(10) "06/06/2017" 
            [5]=> string(10) "06/12/2017" 
            [6]=> string(10) "06/20/2017" 
            } 
    ["exam_code_input"]=> array(7) { 
            [0]=> string(9) "Arabic AL" 
            [1]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            [2]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            [3]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            [4]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            [5]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            [6]=> string(10) "Biology AL" 
            } 
    ["exam_title"]=> array(7) { 
            [0]=> string(34) "Understanding and Written Response" 
            [1]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 3" 
            [2]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 6" 
            [3]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 1" 
            [4]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 2" 
            [5]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 4" 
            [6]=> string(14) "Biology Unit 5" 
            } 
    ["exam_time_input"]=> array(7) { 
            [0]=> string(2) "AM" 
            [1]=> string(2) "PM" 
            [2]=> string(2) "PM" 
            [3]=> string(2) "PM" 
            [4]=> string(2) "PM" 
            [5]=> string(2) "PM" 
            [6]=> string(2) "AM" 
            } 
    ["token"]=> string(32) "bd62bdf4ba8a00174281499decb94d87" 
    ["btSubmit"]=> string(18) "Generate Timetable" 
}
```

Comment: If you cannot bother to format your question so its readable.... Why should we bother answering it?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to sort the "exam_date_input"-Array, right? And it does correspond with the other data, like in "exam_code_input"?

With DateTime::createFromFormat you can create first an DateTime object from your date values (eg 05/08/2017) and then get the Timestamp out of it (getTimestamp()).
Then I would suggest you iterate through your POST-Data like you're already doing and create a new array for better data structure.
Like

```
array( "{THETIMESTAMP}" => {all the other corresponding data, like in exam_code_input} )
```

With ksort() you can sort the array by the keys ascending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own sorting function.

```
function array_sort_by_column(&$array, $column, $direction = SORT_ASC) {
    $reference_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $row) {
        $reference_array[$key] = $row[$column];
    }

    array_multisort($reference_array, $direction, $array);
}
```

And call is like:

```
array_sort_by_column($events_array, 'date');

var_dump($events_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort for this

```
usort($myArray, function($a,$b){
   return ((new DateTime($a['DatesColumn'])) < (new DateTime($b['DatesColumn']))) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Is Date a standard PHP class ? I would use \DateTime instead

Comment: Thank you for correcting this, I was spoiled by auto-correct for too long